# crawler for retrieving regular data - firefox

Tags: regex, firefox-extensions

I need crawler-extension for firefox who could search for all phrases in source code or just in text which are suitable to given regular expression.

Do you know something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I can't try it right now, but maybe [this](http://www.oxymoronical.com/web/firefox/FindBarRX) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I use the free iMacros for Firefox addon and its [search command](http://wiki.imacros.net/SEARCH) for web mining.

```
'Use regular expression to extract data
 SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"_get[Tt]racker\\(([^)]+)\\)" EXTRACT="Tracker is $1"
```